# How to get non-static variable from static function c++ in class?

Tags: c++

I try to find method how to get non-static variable from static func?

In static function, i want to get value from non-static variable.

It is possible?

```
class test {
private:
     static void test();
     string test;
}
```

Comment: Is this C++? Add C++-tag.

Comment: its not possible I recommend you to read bit more about statics

Comment: It's *possible* if you pass an actual `test` instance to your static function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Static member functions can only access static class members. This makes sense, too, if you consider that you can invoke

```
test::test();
```

without instantiating an object. In fact, when executing the code above there may not even be a single class instance.

If you need to access non-static class members from a static member function you need to pass a class instance to it, either a pointer or a reference. When you're doing that, however, you might as well make the static member function non-static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. When you use a static function, you are in static context. Only static members may be accessed, the others don't exist.